# Symfony exception - directory is not writable

Tags: symfony, caching, annotations, var

I have web page based on Symfony 3 framework. Directory `/var` has set writable privilegies on web-data and root. ALL caches, sessions and logs are writted here without problem.

Nevertheless i have still in my prod.log exceptions like this: (Path is still the same - annotations)

> [2018-07-16 13:32:31] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling
>   an exception (InvalidArgumentException: The directory
>   "/var/www/domain.com/var/cache/prod/annotations" is not writable. at
>   /var/www/domain.com/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/FileCache.php
>   line 92) {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0):
>   The directory \"/var/www/domain.com/var/cache/prod/annotations\" is
>   not writable. at
>   /var/www/domain.com/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/FileCache.php:92)"}
>   []

Web looks like run OK - without errors but in logs this exceptions are increasing any time...

For test purpose i write function in controller like this:

```
    $directory = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../var/cache/prod/annotations';

    if (is_writable($directory)) 
        echo "OK: ".$directory;
    else 
        echo "FAIL!: ".$directory;
```

If i call this function VIA BROWSER url i have OK answer...

Comment: And when you have `FAIL` answer? I think that your user doesn't have enough permissions to write to `var/cache` directory. Check that

Comment: Not sure, but you can try - find out which user is running php with a code `print posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];`. I guess in apache it should be www-data user , then grant access for that user with `chown www-data:www-data var/` command

Comment: You can try from official doc - https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd